# Reuse IV for KDF and Encryption

Tags: password-management

So I am writing a password manager (mostly low value, application specific passwords) for a game. I need a way to store a password safely. Light reading suggests using a key derivation function (like pbkdf2), and then encrypt the password using that key (using an algorithm such as AES256).

The KDF takes in a salt, and the encryption too takes an initialization vector. Can I re-use the same salt (suitably large) for both? Or should I store them as two different things?

My database size is fairly small (think ~300 rows). I *can* afford an extra field, but ask if I *need* the extra field.

Comment: You can derive the IV along with the key from the password using PBKDF2.  You should use a random salt each time, and the salt can be stored along with the cipher test.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption for how `openssl enc` does it.

Comment: @mti2935, understood. So if I generate a suitably long “key”, I split it into two, one as the key for the encryption, and one as the IV for the encryption. The IV will be unique by virtue of the salt. Correct?

Comment: That's correct.  The PBKDF2() function should have an input for the number of bytes that it produces.  Use 48.  Then, use the first 32 bytes for the AES key, and the last 16 bytes for the IV.  The key and the IV will be different each time (even if the password is the same) because of the random salt.

Comment: In general for new software I would not use PBKDF2 anymore. There are better successors available like Argon2.